# Find all polynomials which are multiples of $x^2-1$ and have only two nonzero coefficients

Tags: polynomials

I was given a problem to find all polynomials which have a factor $x^2-1$ and have only two nonzero coefficients. I guess the answer is $x^n-1$, where $n$ is an even number which divides 4. But how do I prove that there are no other polynomials that satisfy this condition?

Comment: Where n is an even number?  This means n=6 works, meaning n=3 works

Comment: Typo corrected (n = 2 is also included)

Comment: Let the polynomial be ($x^2$-1)(a$x^n$ + b$x^{n-1}$+......... z)

Comment: This is true, but it has only 2 non-zero coefficients.

Comment: "All polynomials that divide $x^2-1$" are $x-1$ and $x+1$. I think you're after "All polynomials that are divisible by $x^2-1$".

Comment: You mean polynomials which are multiples of $x^2-1$. Are the coefficients required to be integers? What about $x^8-x^2$?

Comment: **Hint**: $P(x)$ is divisible by $x^2-1$ if and only if $P(1)=P(-1)=0$.

Comment: Hint: $P(x)=ax^n+bx^m$

Answer (score 2):

Let the required polynomial be 
$$ p(x) = ax^n + bx^r $$
Clearly p(1) = p(-1) = 0

You can now make cases for n,r being odd or even and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)$ be such a polynomial. Then we have
$$
P(x) = (x^2-1)(a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+a_kx^k)
$$
where $a_n, a_k\neq 0$. Expanding and collecting terms of equal degree, we get
$$
P(x) = a_nx^{n+2} + a_{n-1}x^{n+1} + \cdots +a_{k+1}x^{k+3}+a_kx^{k+2} \\- (a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+a_kx^k)\\
= a_nx^{n+2} + a_{n-1}x^{n+1} + (a_{n-2}-a_n)x^n + \cdots +(a_k-a_{k+2})x^{k+2} -a_{k+1}x^{k+1}-a_kx^k
$$
Now, use the assumption that only two of these terms are non-zero, along with our initial assumption that $a_n, a_k\neq 0$, to reason what all the other terms must be.

Answer (score 0):

To combine two hints, use the division algorithm and write $P(x)$ in two ways $$P(x)=ax^n+bx^m=(x^2-1)q(x)$$for some polynomial $q(x)$. Now put $x=\pm 1$.